# How to use multiple different unique providers in terraform properly

Tags: terraform

I am trying to set up influx/grafana with terraform and I'm having trouble understanding how to use two different providers with one main.tf file. I'm pretty new to terraform so I'm not sure if it's even possible to use only one main.tf as I'm just trying to follow the best practices for file structure. If anyone can give me some pointers that would be great.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your question to share your Terraform code? What happens when you run it? Do you get an error? If so can you include the exact error in the question as well?

Comment: To try it, add a resource from provider one and add a resource from provider two. Then run `terraform init && terraform plan` and it should work. An example would help to answer your question.